# autocomplete jquery post data

Tags: jquery, autocompletar

Necesito enviar datos desde un formulario via post usando el autocompletar de jquery

https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

hasta el momento tengo el siguiente metodo

```
$("#autocompletar").autocomplete(
          "<?php print base_url();?>Controller/Autocompletar/",
          {
                delay:10,
                minChars:1,
                matchSubset:1,
                matchContains:1,
                cacheLength:10,
                onItemSelect:selectItem,
                onFindValue:findValue,
                autoFill:false,
                formatItem:formatItem,
            }
     );
```

Este envia los datos del autocompletar por get, tengo un dato de un input:

```
'dato': $('#id_dato').val(),
```

como puedo mandar este dato usando el autocompletar y capturarlo en el backend que estoy usando php 5

```
$this->input->post('dato');
```

Quizas alguna función del plugin... gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si te entendí bien, esto te ayudará. Agregar la función `onSearchStart` y generar todos los parámetros que deseas enviar a la consulta. En mi caso el *input* asociado al *autocomplete* se llama "`#buscar`".

```
onSearchStart: function () {
    $('#buscar').autocomplete('setOptions', {<b>params</b>: {'s-id': $("#serv-id").val(), 'search': $("#buscar").val()}, });
}
```

Dime como te fue. Saludos !